# How to set timeout on before hook in mocha?

Tags: mocha.js

I want to set timeout value on before hook in mocha test cases. I know I can do that by adding `-t 10000` on the command line of mocha but this will change every test cases timeout value. I want to find a way to change the timeout programmatically below is my code:

```
describe('test  ', () => {

  before((done) => {
        this.timeout(10000);
         ...
```

it will complain about the line `this.timeout(1000)` that `timeout` is not defined. How to set the timeout on before hook.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to set a timeout in your `describe` block rather than in the hook if you want it to affect all the tests in the `describe`. However, you need to use a "regular" function as the callback to `describe` rather than an arrow function:

```js
describe('test', function () {
  this.timeout(10000);

  before(...);

  it(...);
});
```

In all places where you want to use `this` in a callback you pass to Mocha you cannot use an arrow function. You must use a "regular" function which has its own `this` value that can be set by Mocha. If you use an arrow function, the value of `this` won't be what Mocha wants it to be and your code will fail.

You *could* set a different timeout for your before hook but there are two things to consider:

1. Here too you'd need to use a "regular" function rather than an arrow function so:

```js
before(function (done) { 
  this.timeout(10000);
```

2. This would set a timeout only for the `before` hook and would not affect your tests.

Comment: Note that setting the timeout in before, e.g. `before(done => {this.timeout(10000); setTimeout(()=>{done()}, 2500)});`, does **not** work. You must set the timeout before `before`.

Comment: @ericP The example you show does not change the timeout *of the before hook* because you are using an arrow function. So `this.timeout()` executes on the *wrong `this`*. If you change the function you pass to `before` to a regular function, then `this.timeout()` will operate on the correct `this` and the timeout will apply to your `before` hook. That was the first "thing to consider" I listed at the end of my answer.

Comment: The arrow function is explicitly so i *can* access the this of the describe function.
Give it a try with and without arrow functions.

Comment: @ericP I did try it before I responded the first time. What I wrote is correct: if you just change your arrow function to a regular function in the code you show, the code *will* work. You decided to use code which my answer says you should not use, and then it does not work. Well...

Comment: @Louis thanks for the note -- forgot you can't do arrow functions with "this" keywords

Answer (score 13):

as instructed at https://mochajs.org/#hook-level, you have to use a regular function call to set the timeout.

```js
before(function(done) {
  this.timeout(3000); // A very long environment setup.
  setTimeout(done, 2500);
});
```

if you insist on use `arrow` or `async` function in the hook. You may do it this way:

```js
before(function (done) {
  this.timeout(3000);
  (async () => {
    await initilizeWithPromise();
  })().then(done);
});
```

It is quite helpful and nice-looking if you got multiple async calls to be resolved in the hook.

updated: fuction def works well with `async` too. So this hook can be upgraded to

```js
before(async function () {
  this.timeout(3000);
  await initilizeWithPromise();      
});
```

So it provides benefits from both `this` and `await`.

By the way, mocha works pretty fine with `promises` nowadays. If timeout is not a concern. Just do this:

```js
before(async () => {
  await initilizeWithPromise();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also call `timeout()` on the return value from `describe`, like this:

```js
describe('test', () => {
  before(...);
  it(...);
}).timeout(10000);
```

With this approach you can use arrow functions, because you're no longer relying on `this`.

Comment: It still fails with ` Timeout of 2000ms exceeded` with this approach ...

Comment: it won't stop `before` from timeout, it will fail in `before` hook this case also.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this.timeout(milliseconds);` in the before hook is correct. Anyway, you need to use a regular function for the hook (`function (done) ...`) rather than an arrow function (`done => ...`).

```
before(
    function(done) {
        this.timeout(10000);
        ...
    }
);
```

And the reason is that arrow functions have [no `this` binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).