# Wait for DB connection before running tests - event issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm trying to test routes in my express app. App.js is a subapp, when it runs it waits for DB connection and then mounts the routes based on the result.

**app.js**

```
db.connect() // returns a promise
.then(dbConnection => {
  app.use(routes(dbConnection));
  app.emit('dbConnected'); // DB Connected
}).catch(error => {
  // if db connection fails - return 503 for every request
  console.log(`DB connection failed.`);
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Service unavailable');
    error.statusCode = 503;
    error.name = err.name;
    next(error)
  });  
});

module.exports = app;
```

I've written the **app.test.js** to test the routes. I want the tests to wait until the connection is established (because only then the routes are mounted).

**app.test.js**

```
before(function (done) {
  app.on('dbConnected', () => done());
});
// tests go here...
```

The problem is that the 'dbConnected' event is not always caught by the event handler in **app.test.js** and I get **ELIFECYCLE** error.

> 1) "before all" hook:
>        Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

The tests sometimes run correctly, therefore I'm assuming that this is a problem with how I handle the 'dbConnected' event. I'd like to know how to approach this problem properly.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the  timeout ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949895/how-to-set-timeout-on-before-hook-in-mocha

Comment: now I noticed that my before handler is outside of the describe function. Embedding it inside solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a race condition - it's possible that the DB got connected before the test started. In such a case you'll never get the event because it has already fired.

I would check if the DB is connected and only if it isn't I'll wait for the 'dbConnect' event. Something like

```
before(function (done) {
  if (app.isDbConnected) { // set app.isDbConnected when connected.
    process.nextTick(done)
  } else {
    app.on('dbConnected', () => done());
  }
});
```